# ActiveMQ Message Queue Slows Down after 2 million plus message

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a message queue named amq570queue, after accumulating 2 million messages it started to slow down. What broker settings do I need to adjust to fix this issue? I temporarily moved it into a new message queue(in the same broker) and it is working fine. I initially thought that the kahadb has reached its size limit that is why it is getting slow. Is there a way to limit the size of Message Dequeued? Thank you in advance for any inputs.

Regards,
Walter

Comment: you should be able to check the size of your kahadb and memory conmsumption from the web-console in "https://your-host:8443/admin/index.jsp" if the store percent used is reaching 100% ActiveMQ will throttle (block) all producers as no space. Same for memory but when reaching 70% (or depending your settings (memoryUsage and tempUsage)

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is the producer flow control and systemusage settings. Take a look at

http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this is what my activemq.xml(flow control part)                                                 <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="100mb" gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="30000" expireMessagesPeriod="30000">
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
Is the Memory Limit of 100mb have an impact in slowing down the broker?

Comment: It may be the case based on the message size and slow consumers. You may want to calculate limits and set accordingly.